# php array_push not appending the array after the ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am using ajax and php and i would like to append my array each an everytime i make an ajax call. But it is not working.
These are my codes:

```
             $('#multiple_upload_form' +count).ajaxForm({
                    target:'#images_preview'+count,

                    beforeSubmit:function(e){
                    console.log("gud to go");
             },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                    console.log("succeded");
            },
            error:function(data){
                    console.log("failde");
            }
           }).submit();
```

PHP this is the pHP side of it.Plase help

```
<?php
      $questionArr = array();
     if($_POST['image_form_submit']){
             array_push($questionArr,$questionNum );

            if(is_array($questionArr)){
                  foreach($questionArr as $val) {

                    if ($val == $questionNum){
                        $response['response']= "exist";
                          echo json_encode($questionArr);
                    }else{
                       $response['response']= "question does not exist";
                       echo json_encode($response);
                       }
                   }    
           }else{
                       $response['response']= "not array";
                       echo json_encode($response);
           }    
     }
    ?>
```

And this is my HTML

```
         <form             method="post"name="multiple_upload_form"id="multiple_upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="php_work/test.php">

      <input type="hidden" name="image_form_submit" value=""/>
      <input type="file"  name="images[]" id="images" multiple > 
       </form>
```

Comment: <?php

$questionArr = array();
if($_POST['image_form_submit'])
{
 
 
 array_push($questionArr,$questionNum );
 
 if(is_array($questionArr)){
  foreach($questionArr as $val) {
  
  if ($val == $questionNum){
   $response['response']= "exist";
   echo json_encode($questionArr);
  }else{
   $response['response']= "question does not exist";
   echo json_encode($response);
  }
 }

  
 }else{
  $response['response']= "not array";
   echo json_encode($response);
 }
 
 
 
 
}
?>

Comment: You should edit that code into the question instead of adding a comment :)

Comment: Do any of your `console.log()` output works? is the ajax call even submitted? is your form actually a POST or a GET form?

Comment: Thank you i have edited. the ajax call is submitted. i am getting the response back. but the array is not appending.Thanks

Comment: Well, without the relevant HTML form we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you:

```
<?php
 $questionNum = 1; // Or from anywhere you are getting data into it
 $questionArr = array();
 $response['response']= "not array"; // Giving Default value

 if($_POST['image_form_submit']){

  $questionArr[] = $questionNum;
  if(!empty($questionArr)){

    foreach($questionArr as $val) {

      if ($val == $questionNum){
        $response['response'] = "exist";
      }else{
        $response['response']= "question does not exist";
      }

    }

  }

 }

 echo json_encode($response);
 exit;
?>
```

Comment: $questionNum= $_POST['image_form_submit'];     this is where the question number comes from

Comment: it should be dynamic. if the new  question number does not exist in the array, then append array. else return error. thanks

Comment: @trinidado Which type of data you are receiving in `$_POST['image_form_submit']` can you paste in comment?

Answer (score 0):

First: There is one `if` statement in the PHP which won't return a value, since there's no `else`. So if `$_POST['image_form_submit']` is false, nothing is `echo`ed.

Second: `array_push($questionArr, $questionNum);` Where do you defined `$questionNum` in your PHP script?

Third: in your JS: `$('#multiple_upload_form' +count)` there you try to refer to an element with an id with a number I guess? I don't see such an element in your HTML. I also don't see in the JS code where you define `count`.

Long answer short: check both PHP and JS codes for errors.

Comment: $questionNum= $_POST['image_form_submit']; this is where the question number comes from

Comment: For the JS , don't mind the count. it took it out. thanks